# How to use a image stored in a Github repository as a background-image in css?

Tags: css, github, background-image

Im trying to use a an image stored on one of my github repos as a background-image for a website I am developing.

I Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind the hit from waiting for the get request from github, then you can do something like:

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{username}/{reponame}/{branch}/path/to/image.png"); 
}
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest just copying the image local to your website.